# How to simulate a long press with Robolectric?

Tags: android, robolectric

I'm using Robolectric 2.3 to test an Android app. I have a listener registered on a view with `setOnLongClickListener`, and I'd like to test that code by simulating a long click. Is there a helper method to do this in Robolectric? `Robolectric.clickOn` appears to do a normal 'short' tap.

I did see that I can access the long click listener via `ShadowView`, so I suppose I could invoke the callback manually if all else fails.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a `performLongClick()` on the View actually, you should be able to call that from your test to initiate the action.

Here's an example in robo's own unit tests: 
https://github.com/robolectric/robolectric/blob/82202f264ce20ff449d5f8b26f227f88904d7643/robolectric/src/test/java/org/robolectric/shadows/ViewTest.java#L178